# SSRS Report Compliance Issue

Tags: accessibility, standards, section508

We have run into a Section 508 compliance issue with SSRS reports.

Specifically, the issue is with tabular data tables. SSRS reports do not generate table headers with the  tag which is a Section 508 requirement for accessible HTML tables.

After quite some research and debugging we found out a way to make SSRS generate HTML tables in a way that the header cells have Ids and data cells have headers matching the corresponding header Ids. This is very close but still not enough apparently. The  must be used to render the headers (row and col headers).

By the way, there are two provisions regarding accessible HTML tables in Section 508: g and h. Details are found at [Section 508 Laws and Regulations](http://www.section508.gov/section-508-standards-guide#Web).

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 and SSRS version 10.50.4319 and we are displaying, the reports through the ReportViewer (version 10), in ASP.NET web applications running on .NET 4.0.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with SSRS, but 1194.22 g and h are either/or, meaning you don't apply both to the same table. Ideally you would use *g* for basic tables which are [one dimensional<sup>[1]</sup>](http://accessiblehtml.sourceforge.net/html_tables_cookbook.html#contents_item_4.1). You would use *h* for a [multi-leveled table<sup>[1][2]</sup>](http://accessiblehtml.sourceforge.net/html_tables_cookbook.html#contents_item_4.3). To my knowledge, no HTML/XHTML specification says you cannot use the `id`/`headers` method on one-dimensional tables. From a developer's point of view, we should use `scope`s whenever possible, so we don't have to touch every cell.

In your situation, it seems like you must use  the second method.

> This is very close but still not enough apparently. The must be used to render the headers (row and col headers).

Who told you this? If you are working with an agency, I'd request to see if they have a place to get help with 508, for a second opinion, or with the 508 Coordinator, who should roughly say this. Maybe you missed adding an `id` somewhere, which would make the table blow up.

1- This page probably isn't the best source to use, but was the first non-W3C page that had both types of tables.
2- This table is non-compliant.

Comment: Ryan B, Thanks for your reply. I understand 1194.22 g is for simple tables (one logical level of headers) and h is for complicated tables - two or more logical levels of headers. As I mentioned, this is about the HTML that SSRS generates, not from our custom code. What SSRS currently has is not bad. It generates Ids for TD used as headers and the correct Ids set to the headers attribute of of each data cell. Yes, this is the approach Microsoft took for rendering both simple and complicated. What I was asking was: were anyone of you able to get SSRS to create headers with <th>?

Answer (score 0):

Update to my question.

Contacted Microsoft's SSRS team. Their reply was: it was their design to generate table headers with  and data cells like .  No need for further questions.

But still not sure why they chose to render table header with  instead of . Mind boggling.